# Making Facebook Graph API calls from the server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, api

Say I want to revoke a user's login, by making a call to the graph API, I know this can be done with the following command:

```
DELETE /{user-id}/permissions/{permission-name}
```

But how can I implement this command in my c# code? I have the logged in user's access token and code. My website is in asp.net